# Change sharepoint folder name using admin page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Anyone have idea how change folder name using admin page
[Case: Change folder"Insight Marketing Research & Intelligence" to Insight MR&I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/473Gu.jpg)

Comment: Is that the name of your SharePoint site instead of a folder?

Comment: not a programming question...unless you are trying to do it with rest/csom...and then you should have some sample code you tried that didnt work